# sending bulk email with different names in reply address and spam filtering

Tags: email, spam, bulk-email, email-address

I have a web service where I send out bulk email on behalf of customers.  The sending email address is the same for all customers, something like `noreply@mycompany.com`.

When sending out the email on behalf of a customer, I'd like to specify the name of the customer in the email address.

For example, when I send email for ACME Inc., I'd like the the email address to look like:

```
ACME Inc. <noreply@mycompany.com>
```

But I send email on behalf of Globex Corp., I'd like the email address to look like:

```
Globex Corp. <noreply@mycompany.com>
```

I know how to do this, but would using different names with the same sending email address raise any flags with spam filters or email blacklist sites?  Email deliverability is very important.

Comment: Sorry but we already have many questions and answers regarding emails being marked as spam. Spoofing emails is a no no no, using a sent on behalf of is normally ok as long as its transparent but if sending out thousands of emails it'll definitely impact the success rate of your campaign. Follow the advice in the linked question for better delivery or use on behalf off if you must but know it will have some influence.

Comment: Hi @SimonHayter, my specific question is not answered in the linked question so this is definitely not a duplicate.  I'm happy to try my question elsewhere if it is off topic, but I'd prefer you close it for the proper reason. I don't understand the rest of your comment.  I'm definitely not doing any spoofing, just specifying a name corresponding to an email address.  Also, AFAIK, sending emails "on behalf off" someone is an Outlook specific thing which doesn't relate to bulk email.

Comment: Just because you can't find an answer in that question doesn't necessary mean its not duplicate, it is because no one has left a relevant one yet, we have many ways of bumping old questions and improving them via bounties and so forth.

Comment: Furthermore it is not just isolated to Outlook, The “on behalf of” message is added by many mail clients and online web services such as gmail. It’s a very good security feature that helps prevent email spoofing and phishing attacks but in no way does it mean your messages won't be flagged as spam. Sending from the same domain or sub domain increases delivery rate... fact. Currently I see no unique question here since the other one is broad and someone could leave an answer at anytime relevant to what your asking.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the last answer in that question that yours was marked duplicate with, someone has left `If your from address and the server address differ, that could result in spam.` but I've said enough. If you feel your question is unique then please do use our Meta and prompt a different moderator to review this closure.